# Using /execute to detect if player is located at entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Before I say anything, I would like to say that I do not have much experience with commands.

Is there a way to use /execute to detect if a player is located at an entity? I tried `execute if entity @p at @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,limit=1] run say Successful`, but it always returns successful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first see why yours doesnt work and work from there. Your command can be separated in basically 4 parts:

- `execute` Execute command, followed by 2 subcommands
- `if entity @p` If entity @p exists (if any entity is targeted by the selector, `@p` in this case)
- `at @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,limit=1]` Execute at these locations (all entities' location targeted by `@e[...]`)
- `run say Successful` run something with all previous "configurations"

Your command will run at all armorstands, limited to 1, only if there is a player online.

We can run `as` every player and at their location, only if there is an entity close enough. Note here that if the `if` fails after the `as`, only that one entity target by the `as` will stop execution. This would translate to:

- `execute` Normal execute start
- `as @a` Execute as every player (So the next subcommands will run for each entity target by the as, every player in this case)
- `at @s`, `@s` refers to self, whatever that is executing the commands, but in this case it is overwritten by `as @a`. So until this point, we will run as every player, at their own location.
- `if entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,limit=1,distance=..1]` Will only execute if there is an entity who fufills the description (Must be an armorstand, at max 1 block distance)
- `run ...` Note that at this point, @s will refer to the entity that passed successfuly in all test, aka a player who is up to one block of distance from an armorstand. You can do something like `say @s` and it should say the player's name.

In full:

```
execute as @a at @s if entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,limit=1,distance=..1] run say @s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use target selector arguments to select only entities within a 0 block radius / 0 blocks away from the player.

`[distance=0]` will select entities in the same block as the armor_stand.

`[distance=..5]` will select entities up to 5 blocks away from the armor_stand.

(For Bedrock Edition use `r` and `rm` selectors.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors#Selecting_targets_by_distance

Comment: `distance=0` will select entities with the exact same coordinates, rather than the same block.